# How to add a directory to PATH in the file .bashrc?

Tags: bash, path

After installing python(EPDFee), I want to add the /bin directory to $PATH variable. I am use bash shell. I have found that I have to add the following line in the file .bashrc

`export PATH=/home/usrname/epd/bin:$PATH`

I have found the file .bashrc, it reads

`PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin`

`# Added by Canopy installer on 2014-03-29`

`# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1`

`VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /home/an/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate`

Could you please tell me where can I add `export PATH=/home/usrname/epd/bin:$PATH` to or is should be added in another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :
Define a EPD_HOME var and append it to PATH

```
EPD_HOME=/home/usrname/epd/bin    
PATH=$PATH:$EPD_HOME:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Notice that the $EPD_HOME variable is in the PATH variable and is now loaded once you open a connection to your user on the machine.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer! After I add like this,how can I test it to make sure it works?

Comment: That is very easy. You simply open a new terminal to the server and just type `echo $EPD_HOME` and it should print the `/home/usrname/epd/bin`

Comment: @Jianu Thanks! I use echo to test, but the output is a blank line, nothint printed.  Now the **.bashrc** file reads `PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin` `EPD_HOME=/home/an/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin` `PATH=$PATH:$EPD_HOME:$HOME/bin`  `export PATH` `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /home/an/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate`              Is it ok?

Comment: You should group it this way:

    `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
    EPD_HOME=/home/an/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin
    PATH=$PATH:$EPD_HOME:$HOME/bin
    export PATH`

All the variables are declared before the PATH initialization and export. Also, you only need one PATH=$PATH appending, there is no need to use it twice.

Also, please read a comparation of when you should use `.bash_profile` and when you should use `.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

add the following line to your **.bashrc** file ...don't forget to replace your path.

```
export PATH="/path/directory:$PATH"
```

then do

```
source .bashrc
```

to let the changes make effects. I am not sure about other distributions of Linux but It will work on CentOS and RedHat.